# Question about the Sharepoint 2010 VHD

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to install the Sharepoint 2010 image here (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0C51819B-3D40-435C-A103-A5481FE0A0D2&displaylang=en), however, and this is a Sharepoint admin question, how can I handle the following:

-Upgrading SQL Server as new versions are released (I am a Technet member so make the most of the available downloads).
-Is the WCF hotfix installed? This is meant to be installed before Sharepoint installation.
-Is there any limitation, for dev purposes, of having all of these apps on one server/VM? I may want to split the AD to another VM in the future. Apart from the Sharepoint config changes, would this cause any other problems?

As I have licenses for Windows Server, I don't want to get caught in problems with activation. I am assuming I can do an upgrade to another version of Windows Server to avoid the 120 day limit?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you are misunderstanding the purpose of this VM. It is intended as a quick way to give a demo of Office and SharePoint 2010, and do some high level evaluation.

It sounds like you are wanting to make a full-fledged development machine out of it. If that is the case I would say you are better off creating your own VM from scratch so that you can control what is going on with the install.